# Submit a form and refresh to the bottom of the page

Tags: php, html, forms

when submitting a form in php i am using: "header('Location: contact.php');" to redirect back to the current page after hitting submit. However the form is at the bottom of the page and each time submit is hit it is redirected back to the top of the page. is there anyway to redirect back to the bottom of the page?

Comment: Here is an example demonstrated in this page with your post on. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44741542/submit-a-form-and-refresh-to-the-bottom-of-the-page#footer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, You can take a id to part of a page you want to return to and then return to it, see following code:

for example you want to return to bellow div:

```
<div id="bottom"></div>
```

your php code to redirect to this:

```
header('Location: contact.php#bottom');
```

Comment: This option should work well, however be careful about one thing: from the server you can tell a client to use a particular hash, but the server will never receive it back! (eg; `content.php` will not know about `#bottom` unless it's done with client-side js)

Answer (score 0):

You could check if your page was the pre ious page with window.history and if so, scroll down with window.scroll to.

I really recommend to not to that and use AJAX